# Gallio.Model.ModelException: An exception occurred while invoking a test driver

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, mbunit

> Gallio.Model.ModelException: An exception occurred while invoking a
>   test driver. ---> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException:
>   Type 'Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbDebugException' in Assembly 'Gallio,
>   Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=eb9cfa67ee6ab36e' is
>   not marked as serializable. HResult: -2146233076

Getting exception on loading the dll developed in visual studio 2015 in Gallio.Icarus

Comment: I'm running into the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: Is this caused by Gallio not being able to read a .Net 4.6 PDB?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with VS 2017 when I have used ReSharper to build the assemblies. I have changed in the settings, that it should use *MSBUILD 4.0* and this solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Mbunit starting to show it's age. Work around is using older version of MSBuild